# Fill maximal height in css/bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, height

how can I achieve that the map will use the full height?

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column">
<header class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
header
</header>
<main class="flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1">
main
  <div class="map-container row-content">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

css:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.map-container {
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}
```

When I add height 100% to map-container, the height will be too height and a scrollbar is visible.
My footer has a variable height, so I cannot use calc.

Thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/ms582u96/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by add in CSS

```
main {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  position: relative;
}

.map-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```